# Javascript folder in custom mvc is forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

It seems that the `javascript` folder inside the public folder is forbidden for no reason, cause when I access the `css` folder in the same container (public folder) it works fine.
When I try to rename the `javascript` folder to `js` it works properly.

My `.htaccess` file inside the public folder is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: okay sorry.. the problem is when I access the javascript in the URL using "myapp/javascript/"  It return forbidden error. but when i rename the "javascript" folder to "js" folder, and access the js folder using "myapp/js" it works fine. i know i can just change the name of the folder to js and let it stay like that but i just want to know whats causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Otherwise, you're redirecting only if the file/directory exists.

Comment: sorry my bad i wasn't able to include !'s in my question but i already edited it. and i believe it doesn't solve the problem.